# Can webmin create a network interface bond for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, webmin

I just picked up Webmin today after being fed up with using the command line for 6 months for my server running Ubuntu 12.04.  I have liked it so far and have fixed many problems I had before.  I have decided I would like to bond my 2 Ethernet interfaces to double my bandwidth the link aggregation standard.  I googled how to do and came up with one useful page that said click on create new bond under network interfaces.  I apparently don't have that button.  Is there a module I must install?

Comment: Anyone have anything on this?